# amazon aws: не работают openvpn приложения

Tags: windows, openvpn, ec2, amazon-web-services

На ec2 амазона пытаюсь запустить hidemyname клиент (под мастдай), ввожу код, нажимаю коннект - инстант дисконектед. Открыты все порты для openvpn,привязан elastic ip к дедику. в чем проблема может быть?

Логи: https://pastebin.com/i0vLzt9D